# butttons of copy excel pdf do not shown in views?

Tags: django, datatables

I'm trying to make tables with buttons to save and export, excel, csv and pdfs, as well as a field for searching and paginations filters. The tables display the data but the other things are hidden with no errors. I downloaded all the datatables packages and I put it in my static folder:

Here is the code I have:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content%}
<caption>listes des Immobilisations</caption>
    <table id ="table_id" class = "table table-bordered">
    <head class = "alert-success">
        <tr>
            <td>Code immob</td>
            <td>Designation</td>
            <td>Quantite</td>
            <td>Date mes</td>
            <td>Compte immob</td>
            <td>Duree de vie</td>
            <td>Num aut</td>
            <td>Origine</td>
            <td>fournisseur</td>
            <td>N° facture</td>
            <td>Date Facture</td>
            <td>Valeur HT</td>
            <td>Monaie</td>
            <td>Taux cvt</td>
            <td>Taux contre valeur</td>
            <td>Frais d'approche</td>
            <td>Cout d'acquisition</td>
            <td>Reference commande</td>
            <td>Date commande</td>
            <td>Journee</td>
            <td>Compte analytique</td>
            <td>Local</td>
            <td>Mode_amort</td>
            <td>Code_r</td>
            <td>Val_amort</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Code_bar</td>
            <td>Service</td>
            <td>Cni</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for immob in all_immobs %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_code}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_desig}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_qte}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_datemes}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_cptimmob}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_dureevie}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_numaut}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_origine}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_origine}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_fournisseur}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_nufact}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_datefact}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_valht}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_monaie}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_tauxcvt}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_tauxctrval}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_frais}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_coutacq}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_refcmde}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_datecmde}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_journee}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_cptanal}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_local}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_mode_amort}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_code_r}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_val_amort}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_status}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.immo_code_bar}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.service}}</td>
            <td>{{ immob.cni}}</td>
        </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table> 
{% endblock %}  
{% block js %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="{% static   '/DataTables/datatables.min.css' %}"/>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="{% static'/DataTables/datatables.min.js' %}">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#table_id').DataTable({
    buttons:['copy','csv','excel','pdf']


})

} );
</script>
{% endblock js %}
```

Comment: check your browser developer tools for errors. you can't use "paths" in urls in HTML, something like '../../DataTables' is just not a URL.

Comment: i correct the url like that /DataTables.... and always no error in developer tools and buttons are not shown

Comment: Check in your browser the source code. Do you see the correct urls there? Maybe you don’t have a block called `js` in base.html?

Comment: i add block js in base.html then i got this errors in browser  [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c.mData')
 (fonction anonyme) (jquery.min.js:2:31697)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (pdfmake.min.js.map, line 0)

Comment: please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: That’s a javascript error what’s the file not found? There’s a 404 error, for which file is that?

Comment: It ' JQuery.min.js but is existe in folder how i can resolve it

Comment: No the error is happening inside jquery.min.js. That’s not the file that can’t be found. You should see which file cannot be found in the 404 error

Comment: if find this it can help : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in file http:/127.0.0.1/static/Datatables/pdfmake.min.js.map

Comment: i download the file from this link  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pdfmake and i copy it now i got this error  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c.mData') "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/DataTables/datatables.min.js:129:258↵each@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/jquery.min.js:2:271…" – undefined